# Convert Div Content to PDF and save on server path

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf

I want to convert Div content into pdf and save that created pdf file on server path without asking to me save file (download file).

I converted pdf file and aslo saved that file in server path.

But In my code it also shows file download option which I want to remove.

I don't want to give pdf file save as option because I saved created file in server path.

Below is My code:

```
        string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
        string path = Server.MapPath(appPath + "/Attachment/Test.pdf");
        if (File.Exists(path))
            File.Delete(path);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        createDiv.RenderControl(hw);
        var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.End();
```

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the save dialog is showing is because you are writing to the response. If you only want to save to the local disk, simply remove all references to response. You can then do a `Response.Redirect(...)` or similar to point the user to the next page.

**Using MemoryStream**

If you intend to write the PDF to a database you should use a [`MemoryStream` (see MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a `FileStream`. You can then call the [`MemoryStream.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which will return a byte array you can store in the database.

Assuming you are using Entity Framework:

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
//snip
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output);
//snip
myEntityFrameworkObject.Data = output.ToArray();
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. One more question is it possible without saving a pdf file I can get byte array of pdf file because I save byte  of pdf into database.

Comment: A `MemoryStream` is used to keep a file in memory as opposed to a `FileStream` which is used to access the file-system.

Comment: Hi I dont get ur ans. can u plz give guide in my code where I have to change for it.

Comment: For future reference, you should really ask new questions in a new question. Or include these details in the original question.